# Logging in microservice architecture

Tags: logging, microservices, distributed-tracing

We are currently creating an application in .NET framework with the microservice architecture.
As this is an application that'll need to be implemented at our customers, on premise, we require logging. We do not want this to be cloud based, and would like to be able to follow each API call in depth.

What would be the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

FOA after learning some [.Net logging basics](https://www.loggly.com/ultimate-guide/net-logging-basics/), to monitor an application, there are several logging-utilities, such as
[LogExpert](https://github.com/zarunbal/LogExpert) tool to perform logging in windows. [Apache Log4j](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log4j) is very good but will not be compatible with .Net. There are a number of logging tools for .Net, select one from the following two categories:

**A**. [Built-in logging providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#bilp) from the .net framework you can perform logging using: **Console**, **Debug**, **EventSource** and **EventLog** classes to provider logs output to the console, writes log output to the debug provider, writes to a cross-platform event source, and provider sends log output to the Windows Event Log respectively.

**B**. Using a list of [Third-party logging providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#third-party-logging-providers).

For in-depth scientific tasks such as application performance monitoring and dynamic software analysis framework are available, such as [Kieker](https://kieker-monitoring.readthedocs.io/). But for .Net you have to ask for support.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).